# Is it possible to unload a Library and Load a different version of library in run time in Android ?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, jar

Is it possible to dynamically unload a Java library, which is statically linked with the android application (part of build gradle) and load another version of Java library in run time.

Say an example I have an application which uses Picasso library version 1.1.1 and based on the android SDK version (or some business decision) i want to load a different version of Picasso, which will be packed as an asset in the application.

Is it doable ?